# drawing figures with opengl

Tags: c++, opengl

I have an array that contains 0's and 1's and based on the value of the array I want to draw a square and fill it with a color. I have the follow code below, but it only makes 1 square in the middle of the screen. I feel like there is something I need to do with `glVertex2f()` but I'm kind of stumped.

The end result is something like this

[image]

but my code is just one square colored.

```
for (int i = 0; i < Width; i++) {
  for (int j = 0; j < Height; i++) {
    if (myArray[i][j] == 0) {
      glColor(1.1, 1.1, 1.1);
    } else {
      glColor(2.2, 2.2, 2.2);
    }

    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
      glVertex2f(-0.2, 0.2);
      glVertex2f(0.2, 0.2);
      glVertex2f(0.2, 0.2);
      glVertex2f(-0.2, 0.2);
    glEnd;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are drawing all of your squares in the same spot - you need to space them out.

Comment: makes sense. how would i go about finding the x, y on each element. that's what confuses me.

Comment: @Mr.1.0 It's called Math!

Comment: @Vallentin ok but for the first element in the array are the 4 points [0][0] top left [1][0] top right [1][1] bottom left [1][2] bottom right or does that represent the whole element?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a translate in front of each draw.  Something like:

```
glPushMatrix();
glTranslatef(2. * i, 2. * j, 0.0) ;
glBegin(GL_QUADS) ;
...

glPopMatrix() ;
```

Comment: i don't understand those functions i am only familiar with glVertex2f

Comment: @Mr.1.0 You should learn about OpenGL before you try to program with it.